# Angular 2+: Routing based on response from api

Tags: angular

Say I have the following

```
const routes = [
  { 
    path: 'product/:id',
    component: ProductDetailsComponent,
  }
  { 
    path: 'search',
    component: SearchResultsComponent,
  }
]
```

now say

`product/1` - is a movie which is rendered by `DigitalMediaComponent`

`product/2` - is say a TV by `ProductDetailsComponent`

`product/3` - is a washer/dryer bundle, rendered as a `BundleComponent`

`product/4` - is a mattress collection, this includes, a mattress, frames, covers, sheets, pillows, and once can choose a number of things, color, sizes, thread count and such before buying

`product/5` - is an automotive product say a tire, so this renders a `TireComponent` - This needs a fitmentmodule, with year/make/model/trim selection, and many other customizations before one can buy

and the list goes on.

Now obviously, there are some components which are reused between some of these, but overall they are largely different from each other. So I want to lazy load (or lazy download) the javascript files (and css) which contain these components, I dont need the `MoviePreviewComponent` when showing tires.

I have read many examples and they all talk about a very simple case of one to one relation between route and component, like

```
{ path: 'product/:id', loadChildren: 'product/ProductDetailsComponent' }
or
{ path: 'product/:id', loadChildren: () => System.import('./product/ProductDetailsComponent').then(mod => mod.default) }
```

Is there a way where I can

1. call an api upon navigating to a route
2. and based on the response to that api use `System.import('...')` to lazy download the module

I don't want to navigate to an interstitial component and load from there because when the user clicks on a product from search results (or from any other promotional banners throughout the site, which might or might not be built with angular 2), and if it takes a bit for the page to load, they could press `esc` and click something else. This is normal browser behavior and I don't want to lose that

Even if I do end up with an interstitial component, how would I go about loading the dynamic module in?

```
ngOnInit() {
  let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  fetch('/my/api/' + id)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      System.import('./page/' + data.componentType)
        .then(
          // then what do I do to register this module with Angular
          // and replace this in the <router-outlet>
    })

}
```

Comment: you can configure them in the Routing module itself. when are you retrieving the data?

Comment: not following what you mean by routing module. The data has to be retrieved from the api after the user clicks on a product from say search results

Comment: Is this a Single Page Application? If so have the advertising stuff conditioned by an *ngIf isLoading boolean Observable indicator... place that in you main app page.. As for the modularisation part... Still  getting my head round that part too.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:
You can create a dynamic component loader following this link[https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader]. You will just have to create a mapping of you ids and components. Check out this plunkr given in the article[https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview].

Answer (score 0):

I think for good design try to make like this :

```
      ngOnInit(): void {
              this.ServiceOfArray.getArray(id)
            .then(u => this.showData(u));
    }
    enter code here

showData(data: Data) {
        this.data= data;
    }


Service.class
apiEndpoint: "http://localhost:52246/api";

       getArray(Id: number): Promise<SomeData> {
            var url = this.config.apiEndpoint + "/somedata/" + Id;
            return this.http.get(url)
                .map(response => response.json() as SomeData)
                .toPromise();
        }
```